# Multiple submit buttons in Webgrid MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have a WebGrid in My Index  and have two submit buttons to perform separate actions.
Webgrid from this [code](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/09/13/webgrid-helper-with-check-all-checkboxes.aspx)
How to direct to the respective actions when the button is clicked on post.
But When I submit on any of the buttons, the first [HttpPost] Action is only called.
My code :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
    <div id="CheckBoxDiv">
        @grid.GetHtmlWithSelectAllCheckBox(
            tableStyle: "grid", 
            checkBoxValue: "ProductID",
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(columnName: "ProductName"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "Quantity"),
                grid.Column(" ", " ", format: @<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Edit", new { UserID = "12345", partnerid = "111" })">Edit</a>),
                grid.Column(columnName: "Rate"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "Price")                  
            )
         ) 
    </div>
    <p>   
         <input type="image" class="btn" name="command" value="Checkout" src="~/Images/Checkout.PNG" style="width: 62px; height: 25px;"  />
         <input type="image" class="btn" name="command" value="Delete" src="~/Images/Remove.png" style="width: 62px; height: 25px;"  />
    </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Controller Code **

```
[HttpPost]   
public ActionResult Index(string[] selectedRows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)
    {
        var objselected = selectedRows.ToList();
        SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("SpCheckDetails", con);
        scmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", id);
        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partnerID", partnerid);
        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productID", objselected);
        scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     return RedirectToAction("Index","Checkout");
 }

[HttpPost]       
public ActionResult Delete(string UserID, string partnerid, string productid)
{
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cart");
}
```

I tried using this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/12/detecting-which-button-was-clicked-in-mvc.aspx) to call the two actions. But the command value is not called.
Any suggestions.
**EDIT :**

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string id = "12345";
            string partnerid = "xxxxx";
            return View(_service.GetCartDetails(id,partnerid));
        }
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [AcceptParameter(Name = "Checkout")]
    public ActionResult Index(string[] selectedRows, string button)
    {
            return View();
    }
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [AcceptParameter(Name = "Delete")]
    public ActionResult Delete(string[] selectedRows,string UserID, string partnerid, string productid)
    {
            return View();
    }
```

**View code**

```
<input type="image" class="btn" name="Checkout" value="Checkout" src="~/Images/Checkout.PNG"/>
<input type="image" class="btn" name="Delete" value="Delete" src="~/Images/Remove.png" />
```

I used  ActionMethodSelectorAttribute for getting the button value. But It still goes to the Index View whichever button is clicked. 
Is there any mistake in my code. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use **ActionMethodSelectorAttribute** interface which will identify which button is click. for more info refer the following link
http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2009/05/31/asp-net-mvc-multiple-buttons-in-the-same-form.aspx

Comment: I tried using the ActionMethodSelectorAttribute. But both the actions are not called separately. In the example, they used buttons to submit. But In my case, I am using two images for submit. Will that be the mistake ??

Comment: no have you given different name to both submit button?, it would be better if show me some code snap so that i will able find out what exact issue.

Comment: since I used the input type as image, the submit is not going to the respective action. so I changed my  input  type as button and got the output.

Comment: ohhh it's because "IsValidForRequest" method you have taken button name from Form Collection that's why it's work..